# getting java.lang.NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, firebase, android-ndk, crashlytics

I am using firebase crashlytics beta version for ndk crashes. I am following all the steps given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?authuser=1&platform=android). But I am facing an issue and can not upload symbol file. Whenever I am going to run the task `./gradlew uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug --stacktrace` it says `java.lang.NullPointerException`. But why and where it is null?

here is the full stacktrace of this task

```
> Task :app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug'.
> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:generateCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:151)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$3.accept(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:148)
        at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:191)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:141)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:108)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveBeforeExecutionOutputsTaskExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveAfterPreviousExecutionStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.execute(FinalizePropertiesTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskExecutionModeExecuter.java:95)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:56)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.executeTask(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter$1.call(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.EventFiringTaskExecuter.execute(EventFiringTaskExecuter.java:49)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.LocalTaskNodeExecutor.execute(LocalTaskNodeExecutor.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:355)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$InvokeNodeExecutorsAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:343)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:336)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionGraph$BuildOperationAwareExecutionAction.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionGraph.java:322)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:134)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.execute(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:202)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.executeNextNode(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:193)
        at org.gradle.execution.plan.DefaultPlanExecutor$ExecutorWorker.run(DefaultPlanExecutor.java:129)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processDebugInfoEntry(DwarfDataParser.java:297)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processChildDebugInfoEntries(DwarfDataParser.java:269)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.processCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:194)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:173)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.readCompilationUnit(DwarfDataParser.java:139)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.dwarf.DwarfDataParser.parse(DwarfDataParser.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parseElf(ElfDataParser.java:132)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.elf.ElfDataParser.parse(ElfDataParser.java:39)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.ElfCSymFactory.createCSymFromFile(ElfCSymFactory.java:92)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:101)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateCodeMappings(NdkCSymGenerator.java:90)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.ndk.internal.csym.NdkCSymGenerator.generateFromDirectories(NdkCSymGenerator.java:44)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools.generateNativeSymbolFile(Buildtools.java:157)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.Buildtools$generateNativeSymbolFile$3.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.crashlytics.buildtools.gradle.tasks.GenerateSymbolFileTask.generateSymbols(GenerateSymbolFileTask.groovy:45)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:103)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:48)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:28)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:702)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:669)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$5.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:404)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.run(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:393)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:376)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.access$200(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$TaskExecution.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:213)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.lambda$execute$1(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ExecuteStep.execute(ExecuteStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:58)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CleanupOutputsStep.execute(CleanupOutputsStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveInputChangesStep.execute(ResolveInputChangesStep.java:33)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CancelExecutionStep.execute(CancelExecutionStep.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.executeWithoutTimeout(TimeoutStep.java:73)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.TimeoutStep.execute(TimeoutStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CatchExceptionStep.execute(CatchExceptionStep.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CreateOutputsStep.execute(CreateOutputsStep.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SnapshotOutputsStep.execute(SnapshotOutputsStep.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.executeWithoutCache(CacheStep.java:201)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:70)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.CacheStep.execute(CacheStep.java:45)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.execute(BroadcastChangingOutputsStep.java:49)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.StoreSnapshotsStep.execute(StoreSnapshotsStep.java:32)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.RecordOutputsStep.execute(RecordOutputsStep.java:24)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.executeBecause(SkipUpToDateStep.java:96)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.lambda$execute$0(SkipUpToDateStep.java:89)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.SkipUpToDateStep.execute(SkipUpToDateStep.java:38)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:77)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveChangesStep.execute(ResolveChangesStep.java:37)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:36)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.legacy.MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.execute(MarkSnapshottingInputsFinishedStep.java:26)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.steps.ResolveCachingStateStep.execute(ResolveCachingStateStep.java:48)
        at org.gradle.internal.execution.impl.DefaultWorkExecutor.execute(DefaultWorkExecutor.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:120)
        ... 35 more
```

I have followed all the steps from firebase ndk crashlytics. but no luck

here is my app-level `build.gradle` file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ndk.demo"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                //version "3.10.2"
                cppFlags "-std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions"
                abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
            }
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }

    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            enable true
            reset()
            include "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
            exclude "armeabi"
            universalApk true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
//                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
        }

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
            firebaseCrashlytics {
                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
//                mappingFileUploadEnabled true
            }
        }
    }

    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    packagingOptions {
        doNotStrip "*/armeabi/*.so"
    }
}

/*afterEvaluate {
    if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleDebug")) {
        assembleDebug.finalizedBy("uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug")
    } else if (gradle.startParameter.taskNames.contains(":app:assembleRelease")) {
        assembleRelease.finalizedBy("uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileRelease")
    }
}*/

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'


    //new crashlytics
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.0.0-beta01'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply from: "../artifacts.gradle"
```

Someone please help me to solve out this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you remove `nativeSymbolUploadEnabled` for both debug and release inside the `buildTypes`, do you still get the NPE?

Comment: @harrytmthy without `nativeSymbolUploadEnabled` how will I run `uploadCrashlyticsSymbolFileDebug` task?
this is a required parameter for ndk crashlytics

Comment: I’m running into the same issue with our project and reported it via GitHub here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/1357. I also contacted their dev support and they say the team is currently investigating this. My guess is that it’s caused by parsing one of our static libraries.

Comment: I don't know why, but now I'm not getting this error now. I had done some changes but what I can't remember it.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do assemble, install and run together. Especially if you have parallel builds enabled, that would be a problem. install and installDevice are different. install is coming from Android plugin and installs on all devices. installDevice is from our plugin and installs on a given device. First one by default, can be overridden with -PdeviceId=

Can you try following things:

Can you share your gradle and Android plugin version with us?
Try with just ./gradlew runDebug. This will assemble and install for you.
You can also do startDebug after a regular Android installDebug task. This will just start rather than install and start which is useful if you need to run install task yourself.
If you have parallel enabled, can you try with --no-parallel command line argument?

Comment: thanks for the reply, can you please elaborate your answer? I can't understand what you are saying. What is install and installDevice and -PdeviceId=. Where will I find this? And I don't have any task named `runDebug`. How will I run this task?

Comment: Please note that without `afterEvaluate` I can run the app successfully

Comment: I am using 3.5.3 `gradle` version

Comment: "I am using firebase crashlytics beta version for ndk crashes", that is your problem, report this bug and hope for a fix!